# Ruby on Rails - Module config instance variable sets to nil unexpectedly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm dealing with strange problem in Ruby on Rails. 
In *app/lib/cml.rb* I have:

```
module CML
  class << self
    attr_accessor :scheduler
    def configure
      yield self
      true
    end
  end
end
```

Then I have in *config/initializers/cml.rb*:

```
CML.configure do |config|
  config.scheduler = "hey"
end
```

*app/controllers/example_controller.rb*

```
class ExampleController < ApplicationController
    def action1
        logger.debug "Scheduler: #{CML.scheduler}"
        puts ""
    end
end
```

*app/config/routes.rb*

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/action1', to: 'example#action1'
end
```

Problem:

1. start server
2. remove puts line from example_controller.rb#action1
3. request /action1

Expected behaviour: In log I see "Scheduler: hey". 
Reality: In log I see "Scheduler: " (in byebug I see it's nil)

Github repo with example app: https://github.com/luki215/rails-module-error

What am I doing wrong? I see that this kind of configuration is commonly used along several gems and these gems are working just fine.Thank you!

Comment: You're not doing anything wrong, this should work fine as you describe it. You need to include a reproducible example, ideally in pure Ruby, that demonstrates this problem for us to help in solving it, we can't really help since the behaviour you describe really can't be reproduced with the code you've given us.

Comment: The one thing I will mention is that you need to stop and restart your Rails server when editing things in `config/`, those changes will not be automatically reloaded between requests.

Comment: Sorry, I added steps to reproduce & isolated problem I'm having. I couldn't isolate it from Rails because I think that it is something related to how Rails loads modules in development.

Comment: @LukášBřezina: if you can't isolate this into a short self-sufficient snippet, the next best thing is create a dummy app with this problem and post it to github. Without seeing the problem, we can't really tell what's going on.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Thank you for tips, github repo added.

Comment: Indeed, rails reloads `CML` for some reason. (but doesn't run its initializer, of course). At the moment I can't tell why it does this. I'll try to take another deeper look later today.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev have you figured out something?

Comment: @meagar Could you please cancel [on hold] status? I've updated question so that the problem is clear.

Comment: @LukášBřezina: nah, didn't have the time...

Comment: The example works when I clone it, run `bundle install` and `rake:db migrate` in the folder and start the server. I'm using Windows 10 + Ruby 2.4.2 and bundle installed Rails 5.1.6 for me.

Comment: @JohanWentholt: it works fine the first time, yes. Did you then edit the file and reload the page?